# PyPi package versions compatible with Cloud Composer's `apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure`

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dependencies, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm attempting to load a few packages into an instance of Google Cloud Composer 2. I constantly getting dependency or package issues and am unable to get the versions of the packages that function.

The `requirements.txt` file that keeps failing looks like

```
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure == 8.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-google <= 10.11.1
numpy == 1.26.2
pandas == 2.1.3
datetime == 5.3
```

I found that I can load the requirements.txt file directly to the cloud composer environment using

```
gcloud composer environments update [ENVIROMENT] --location [LOCATION] --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt  --verbosity=debug
```

where `[ENVIROMENT]` is the cloud composer environment and `[LOCATION]` is the location.

Comment: Hi @user4933, Are you getting any error message while using the `requiremnts.txt` file ? If yes, could you share the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

In the `Cloud Composer` environment, the packages for `Google Cloud` are already installed in the machines.

In your `requirements.txt` file, you added the following package :

```
apache-airflow-providers-google <= 10.11.1
```

And this package already exists in `Composer`.

The risk is to have conflicts between this version and the version used by `Composer`.

To check the version used by `Composer`, you can check this link [Composer versions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions)

For each Composer version, you can see all the `Python` packages with their versions installed in the machines.

Example for the version `composer-2.5.2-airflow-2.6.3` of `Cloud Composer` :

[image]

You have to be carreful, the `pandas` and `numpy` appear in the list and are already installed in `Composer`.

It's better to only pass the package concerning `Azure` :

```
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure == 8.3.0
```

Comment: @user4933 have you solved your issue ?